# Java print character by character

Tags: java

So I have used a little function called typePhrase, and it allows me to give it any string, and it will print it in the console, letter by letter.

```
public static String typePhrase(String phrase) {
    for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 50) {

        }
        System.out.print(phrase.charAt(i));
    }
    return " ";
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make a function like this, but print lots of letters at once, for instance, every 50 milliseconds it would print out 7 letters all together. The code that I am using now, prints one letter every 50 milliseconds.

Comment: You can print however many characters you want as long as you check the length and make sure that you don't exceed the array indices i.e. cause IOBException.

Comment: Look at `Thread.sleep(50)` instead of the while (=busy loop). And compare in the Task Manager the CPU load. J)

Comment: @ha9u63ar I think you mean IOException not IOBException,cause i can not find something like that on internet.

Comment: @GoXr3Plus I believe ha9u63ar is referring to `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @AndyTurner     You're right there sir!

Comment: @ha9u63ar although in this case it would be a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i += 7) {
```

and

```
phrase.charAt(i)
```

to

```
phrase.substring(i, Math.min(i + 7, phrase.length())
```

Comment: just like ha9u63ar said, will this be able to stop the IOBException? or would i have to do a try / catch also?

Comment: @R.Duggan       The loop will be gone if i steps out of the array length so yes it will work without a try catch. But using try catch in these cases are helpful in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @R.Duggan there is no IOBException here, that is handled by the loop guard and the `Math.min`.